# Ruby string to operator

Tags: ruby, string, operators

I have an array

```
operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
```

And I want to use them to solve an equation in 4 different ways. I imagine it would be something like this:

```
operator.map {|o| 6 o.to_sym 3 } # => [9, 3, 18, 2]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do as below using [***`Object#public_send`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method :

```
operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
operator.map {|o| 2.public_send o,2 }
# => [4, 0, 4, 1]
```

One more way using [***`Object#method`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-method) and [***`Method#call`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-call):

```
operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
operator.map {|o| 2.method(o).(2) }
# => [4, 0, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by using a `try`. The reason try is probably preferred is that `try` is a more defensive version of send.

```
def try(*a, &b)
  if a.empty? && block_given?
    yield self
  else
    __send__(*a, &b)
  end
end
```

Doing this with a `try` would look like this:

```
operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
val_to_be_operated = nil

operator.map { |v| val_to_be_operated.try(v, 2) } 
# => [nil, nil, nil, nil]
operator.map { |o| val_to_be_operated.method(o).(2) } 
# Error

val_to_be_operated = 2 
operator.map { |v| val_to_be_operated.try(v, 2) }
# => [4, 0, 4, 1]
```