# How to pass operator as a parameter in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here is what I have:

`operator = '>'`

Here is what I tried:

```
5 operator.to_sym 4

#invalid result => 
5 :>= 4
```

**Expected**:
`5 > 4`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `public_send` or (`send` depending the method):

```
operator = :>
5.public_send(operator, 4)
# true
```

`public_send` (as `send`) can receive a method as String or Symbol.

In case the method you're using isn't defined in the object class, Ruby will raise a `NoMethodError`.

---

You can also do `receiver.method(method_name).call(argument)`, but that's just more typing:

```
5.method(operator).call(4)
# true
```

Thanks @tadman for the benchmark comparing `send` and `method(...).call`:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  repeat = 10000000

  bm.report('send')        { repeat.times { 5.send(:>, 2) } }
  bm.report('method.call') { repeat.times { 5.method(:>).call(2) } }
end

#              user       system     total    real
# send         0.640115   0.000992   0.641107 (  0.642627)
# method.call  2.629482   0.007149   2.636631 (  2.644439)
```

Comment: `send` is the recommended method. The `method` approach is [about 5x slower](https://gist.github.com/tadman/ed6bf2f9e9b2bb68a8818cc52075495e) but is useful in other situations where `send` isn't practical.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Ruby string to operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019668/ruby-string-to-operator) - you need to use public send:

```
operator = '>'
5.public_send(operator, 4)
=> true
operator = '-'
5.public_send(operator, 4)
=> 1
```